# Problems trying to implement Java Sockets example

Tags: java, sockets, file-io, io

I am trying to implement this example here: [Reading from and Writing to a Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)

I copied and pasted the code into NetBeans. I changed the port name "taranis" to "localhost" and tried to run the example, but I got the error:

> run: Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: localhost. Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

I also tried to substitute localhost for my actual hostname of my laptop, but it gives the similar error.  Can you help pinpoint what I am doing wrong?

Edit: In regards to Mark's recommendation, when I substitute

```
System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + "the connection to: localhost.");
```

with

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

I get:

```
run:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
        at EchoClient.main(EchoClient.java:12)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: Is there a process that is listening for connections on `localhost:7`?

Comment: What OS are you running this on? If Linux/Unix you will need to run it using sudo. Alternately change the port that it binds to at > 1024.

Comment: I am using Windows XP.  I don't have any other processes running. I thought port 7 would automatically echo back the results, hence not needing a socket server for this example. Please let me know if I am incorrect.   Thanks~

Comment: Try replacing the custom error printing (`System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: taranis.");`) with `e.printStackTrace()`.  The stack trace and exact error message would be more useful here than a general non-descriptive message.

Comment: Hi Mark, my results from e.printStackTrace() are shown above in my post.  It seems hard to decipher. Do you or anyone else see what is wrong? Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The echo service is not listening. Why not write your own? Run the application below and change your client to connect to the same port (8000).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class EchoServer {

    private static final int PORT = 8000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + PORT);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println("Echo server started");

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("echoing: " + inputLine);
            out.println(inputLine);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Btw, the next example (knock-knock server) does work and gives a nice example of using a 'protocol' class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the echo service is running by default, when I tried a quick test it on my Win XP client, it did not work:

```
H:\>telnet localhost 7
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 7: 
Connect failed

H:\>
```

So to make your code work, you could try pointing it to a server that has the echo service running.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the echo service is commonly disabled by default. I'm using windows 7, to enable it I followed the instructions found here:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/windows-7-simple-tcpip-services-what-how.html

Example worked fine for me afterwards.

For XP:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_simptcpinstall.mspx?mfr=true